# Agregar en ActionBar

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Quisiera saber como agregar un icono en la ActionBar de mi aplicación tengo el siguiente código XML

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

   </menu>
```

Pero no tengo la carpeta "menu" no estoy seguro donde agregarlo o como hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si con agregar iconos, te refieres a incorporar acciones en la `ActionBar`, lo que tienes que hacer es crear dentro de la carpeta ***res***, un directorio llamado ***menu***, y ahí dentro metes el *XML*.

Luego en la actividad donde quieras incorporar este menú añade:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nombredelxml, menu);
    return true;
}
```